# php "include()" security flaw?

Tags: php, security, include

In the PHP manual for `include`, there is a user contribution that states the following:

> include() when used to load configuration information has a scary
>   security flaw, if someone corrupts the PHP header in the included file
>   it will happily print the config file to every page which includes it
>   as plain text.
>
> Luckily there is a quick and easy workout for this behaviour (which is
>   alluded to in this article):

```
<?php
ob_start();//Hook output buffer
include("config.php");
ob_end_clean();//Clear output buffer
?>
```

I know that the following will prevent any output until the output buffer is cleared/unhooked/whatever. However, what I am unsure about, is the `if someone corrupts the PHP header in the included file` - is that something that can be done client-side / remotely, or would that be if I accidentaly gave the php file a different file extension?

To make a long story short: How COULD an outside user corrupt the php header?

Comment: Also slightly relevant: You can always move such files outside the document root to at least eschew visibility issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, let's say you've got a file `seekritpasswords.php` that you include, and it contains your database credentials. You'd have a file that looks something like:

```
<?php

$db_user = 'fred';
$db_passwd = 'barney';
$db_name = 'wilma';
$db_host = 'betty';
```

The php "header" is the `<?php` portion. If that becomes corrupted, say by adding a space to it, or removing it entirely, etc... Then the file is no longer a php script, as it does not contain the header which triggers "php mode". it'll just be plain text, and gets treated as regular output like any other plain text file. Remember, there's no such thing as a PHP script. There's only files which contain one or more PHP blocks, and those blocks are delimited by `<?php  ?>` tag sets.

Comment: I dont think the <?php will work in a HTML document though, unless the PHP engine has been told to parse in that file type?

Comment: @jeff: if you're using `include()` or `require()` on it, PHP will run it through the parser, regardless of file extension. But only code within `<?php ?>` blocks will actually be executed. Everything else will be output by default instead.

Answer (score 1):

If someone corrupts ANY file that PHP is including you face this problem. I have no idea what that user was allowing (web edits of the `config.php`...?) but that file should only be edited by server admins and the developers.

Alowing modifications of a file like config.php would allow someone to do something like this which sounds like what that user is describing.

```
// Removed: <?php

$config = array(
 ...

);

// removed: ?>
```

The PHP core will parse any file given to it (regardless of the `.php` extension) so only valid project files should be included. Never include files based on user input.

Comment: Right - this is just a theoretical question, like how WOULD someone be able to corrupt the php header? Will add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

What they are saying is that if someone can edit your PHP file (by removing `<?php` for example), then your configuration info will simply be sent to the browser, as PHP will no longer be parsing it.

The workaround they suggest simply nukes any output from your config file.

As @Niklas says, if someone can edit your files, then the damage is done anyway.  No this can't be done remotely (short of a serious screw-up in your code or some other vulnerability), and no, if you include PHP with a different extension, PHP will still parse it.  Beware though, if someone requests that file with their browser, PHP will not parse it, as it is up to the web server to determine file type and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Any file included is treated as a PHP source file. That is, if has an opening php tag <?php, it will be executed, otherwise it will be printed.

Generally it is not possible to modify a file remotely through a web server, but if an attacker gains access to the server by other means (SSH, FTP etc.), and can write the file, the file could be modified.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like a bit of paranoia.  If someone (other than you) can corrupt the PHP header (and we're talking about the

If someone is doing this as part of the development process I would hope that you were not developing on your production system.  You should have a development box and push your updates to production.